# Using 'Featured Img' in WP for custom slider

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Below is the bit of markup I have for my List items via my slider, I'm wondering what to include as img source, for a featured image via the post editor to be brought in as that image for the slider.

```
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><img src="" alt="" style="display:none;"/><span><?php the_title(); ?><br /><p class="info" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></span></a></li>
```

I've also tried inserting this bit of PHP for `img src <?phpthe_post_thumbnail('slider_image'); ?>`

*The full code I have:*

```
<div id="content"> 


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<!--Your slider code goes here-->


        <div id="featured" >  
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">

           <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><img src="" alt="" style="display:none;"/><span><?php the_title(); ?><br /><p class="info" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></span></a></li>  

           <?php endwhile; ?>

            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><img src="" alt="" style="display:none;"/><span><?php the_title(); ?><br /><p class="info" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></span></a></li>  

            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><img src="" alt="" style="display:none;"/><span><?php the_title(); ?><br /><p class="info" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></span></a></li>  

            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-4"><a href="#fragment-4"><img src="" alt="" style="display:none;"/><span><?php the_title(); ?><br /><p class="info" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></span></a></li>  
         </ul>  


         <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!-- First Content -->  
        <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">  
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('slider_image'); ?>" alt="" />  
            <div class="info" >  
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>  
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >read more</a></p>  
            </div>  
        </div>  

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <!-- Second Content -->  
        <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">  
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('slider_image'); ?>" alt="" />  
            <div class="info" >  
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>  
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >read more</a></p>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <!-- Third Content -->  
        <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">  
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('slider_image'); ?>" alt="" />  
            <div class="info" >  
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>  
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >read more</a></p>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <!-- Fourth Content -->  
        <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">  
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('slider_image'); ?>" alt="" />  
            <div class="info" >  
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a></h2>  
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >read more</a></p>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  

<!--Your slider code goes here-->
<!-- End Featured Lists Image Slider -->        

<?php endif; ?>
```

Possibly more in depth at: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?840162-Help-with-Theming-my-jQuery-CSS-slider-in-WP-to-Dashboard!!&p=5084697#post5084697

*But no such luck, any suggestions?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the_post_thumbnail doesn't have a size defined like 'slider_image'. you can use 'full','large','medium' and 'thumbnail' for that except you can use array(width,height) for different resolutions.

Second, I think you are referring a 'custom field' by using "slider_image" which you can't get by the_post_thumbnail() function.

Does your posts have a custom field named "slider_image"? If so, you can get them by using the methods explained [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values)

Comment: add_image_size('slider_image', 940, 340, true); here adds the thumbnail size, ok.. which should've been mentioned. and the second question is : are your posts' featured images defined?